# True/False condition in matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix and would like to see if the entries are larger than a certain value,e.g:

```
matrix[matrix[,1] > value,1]
```

Now this will return all values that are larger than `value`

What I would like to do instead of this is just get `TRUE/FALSE` in order to be able to use it in an if condition.

So I would like to check if any value in the matrix is `TRUE` for the above condition.

Comment: yes but I would only like to check for the first column

Comment: Try `matrix[, 1] > value`

Comment: Close vote note: Noting the preamble to the choice for "Not constructive" is "As it currently stands, ..." If this had a data example, then all the guessing that is currently in evidence would not be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)

a <- matrix(round(runif(25,0,4)), nrow=5)
a

b <- (a>2)
b

class(b)
```

a is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    3    3    3    1
[2,]    2    0    2    1    1
[3,]    2    1    1    1    1
[4,]    2    3    4    1    0
[5,]    3    2    1    1    1
```

b is:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

class(b) returns:

```
[1] "matrix"
```

If you want a numeric matrix of 1 / 0 instead of TRUE / FALSE you can then use:

```
b[b==TRUE] = 1
b

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    1    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

This code will only check the first column:

```
b2 <- a[,1] > 2
b2

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```